# How to hide small edit button beside many2one field in openerp

Tags: button, odoo, edit

I want to remove the small edit button that appears beside a many2one field in openerp. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You can make it a selection fields.

Comment: Then the domain won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this with your `many2one` field

```
options='{"no_open": True}'
```

For example I don't want to navigate menu with currency_id than I use

```
<field name="currency_id" options='{"no_open": True}'/>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanx Odedra. Can I also do this based on the user group?

Comment: that i don't know about it and might be tricky but if you go with user group than it will hide the field means you don't see that field without user group.